# Reward not increasing while training a Bipedal System

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient-descent

I am completely new to reinforcement learning and this is my first program in practice. I am trying to train the bipedal system in the OpenAI gym environment using the policy gradient algorithm.

However, the reward never changes, either at episode 0 or at episode 1000 and I cannot figure out what is going wrong. Could anyone please help me..

TIA.

The code is as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy
from torch.autograd import Variable
import gym

def train(model, name):
    model.train()
    env = gym.make(name)
    env.reset()
    num_episodes = 20000
    max_steps = 10000
    optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1)
    numsteps = []
    rewards = []
    avg_numsteps = []

    min_reward = -1000

    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        state = env.reset()
        probs = []
        rewards = []

        for steps in range(max_steps):
            action, log_prob = model.action(state)
            env.render()
            state, reward, finished, _ = env.step(action.squeeze(0).detach().numpy())
            env.render()
            probs.append(log_prob)
            rewards.append(reward)
            if finished:
                break

        if finished:
            Rewards = []
            for i in range(len(rewards)):
                G = 0
                p = 0
                for reward in rewards[i:]:
                    G = G + 0.9 * p * reward
                    p = p + 1
                Rewards.append(G)

            Rewards = torch.tensor(Rewards)

            discounted_reward = (Rewards - Rewards.mean()) / (Rewards.std() + 1e-9)

            gradients = []
            for log_prob, G in zip(log_prob, discounted_reward):
                gradients.append(-log_prob * G)

            optim.zero_grad()
            policy_gradient = Variable(torch.stack(gradients).sum(), requires_grad=True)
            policy_gradient.backward()
            optim.step()
            numsteps.append(steps)
            avg_numsteps.append(numpy.mean(numsteps[-10:]))
            rewards.append(numpy.sum(rewards))

            print("episode: {}, total reward: {}, average_reward: {}, length: {}\n".format(episode,
                                                                                           numpy.sum(rewards),
                                                                                           numpy.round(numpy.mean(
                                                                                               rewards[-10:]),
                                                                                                       decimals=3),
                                                                                           steps))

        if numpy.sum(rewards) > min_reward:
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), '/home/atharva/policyNet.pth')
            min_reward = numpy.sum(rewards)


def test(model, name):
    env = gym.make(name)
    model.eval()
    state = env.reset()
    with torch.no_grad():
        while True:
            action, log_prob = model(state)
            state, reward, finished, _ = env.step(action.squeeze(0).numpy())
            env.render()
            if finished:
                break


class PolicyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputs, actions, hidden_size):
        super(PolicyNet, self).__init__()
        self.num_actions = actions
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(inputs, hidden_size)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 2*hidden_size)
        self.layer4 = nn.Linear(2*hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.layer5 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, actions)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.layer4(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.layer5(x)
        return x

    def action(self, state):
        state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0)
        actions = self.forward(Variable(state))
        #prob = numpy.random.choice(self.num_actions, p=numpy.squeeze(actions.detach().numpy()))
        log_prob = torch.log(actions.squeeze(0))
        return actions, log_prob
```

and the calling is as follows

```
from REINFORCE import PolicyNet, train

model = PolicyNet(24, 4, 256)
train(model, 'BipedalWalker-v3')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your learning rate is way too high! High learning rate may lead your model to never converge (in fact, the loss may diverge). A learning rate that is way too low will make the training process unnecessarily long. There is a trade-off you have to find for yourself.

Tunning your learning rate may have a tremendous impact on the performance of your model. I can recommend you spending some time reading this (quite well written) blog post: https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-rate-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/

For starters, try a learning rate that is in the range `[0.01, 0.00001]`. For instance:

```
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

Comment: The learning rate was 1e-2 to 1e-5 before and still did nothing happened.. so that is when I got frustrated and kept it as 1... I believe the model parameters are not being updated hence the reward and loss etc remain the same....

Comment: not sure if that will make a difference, but replace `actions = self.forward(Variable(state))` with `actions=self.__cal__(torch.tensor(state))`. By calling forward directly you skip some hooks that thare used in the backward pass.

Comment: Deep Reinforcement Learning is notorious for its sensitivity to hyperparameters. It could be a bug in your training, but often it gets down to finding the correct hyper parameters to make it work. You can check here for some examples that do work: https://github.com/VictorZuanazzi/Project_RL.git and https://github.com/VictorZuanazzi/ReinforcementLearning-2/blob/master/lab2.ipynb

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check them out.